# An alternative of swprintf_s in Linux (or Android platform)

Tags: android, visual-c++, clang

While porting code from C++ (written and compiled in CL compiler) to Android (CLANG compiler) I am getting following error: 
no matching function for call to ['swprintf_s'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce3zzk1k.aspx)

`swprintf_s` is Microsoft specific function with added security of buffer overloading.

What should be the best way to replace this function without removing the added benefits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`swprintf` is really the only portable option. Include `<wchar.h>`, and possibly, `<stdio.h>`.

This already has the 'security feature' limiting the number of wide characters written to the wide string - according to the C99 specification. It should not be expected to validate formatting parameters at run-time however. Modern compilers like clang *may* be able to detect some suspect format strings at compile time. Use the `-Wall` option.